# Continuity of P-laplacian

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Define
$$\langle -\Delta_p u, v \rangle_{(W^{1,p}_0)', W^{1,p}_0} = \int_{\Omega}|\nabla u |^{p-2}\nabla u \nabla v.$$
Show that $-\Delta_p$ is continous from $W^{1,p}_0$ to $(W^{1,p}_0)'$.

I showed that for every sequence $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $W^{1,p}_0$ such that $u_n \rightarrow u$ in $W^{1,p}_0$, and for all $v \in W^{1,p}_0$ :
$$\langle -\Delta_p u_n, v \rangle \rightarrow \langle -\Delta_p u, v \rangle$$
How to conclude that $-\Delta_p u_n \rightarrow -\Delta_p u $ in $ (W^{1,p}_0)'$

I tried to use Banach Steinhaus theorem, but I couldn't reach the result.

Answer (score 1):

Since $u_n \to u$ in $W^{1,p}$ there is a subsequence (denoted by same index) such that
$\nabla u_n(x) \to \nabla u(x)$ for almost all $x$, and there is a function $g\in L^p$ such that $|\nabla u_n(x)| \le g(x)$ for almost all $x$.

Then conclude that $|\nabla u_n|^{p-2}\nabla u_n \to |\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u$ in $L^{p'}$
by dominated convergence theorem, where $\frac1p+\frac1{p'}=1$.

Comment: Yeap i showed that $|\nabla u_n |^{p-2}\nabla u \rightarrow |\nabla u |^{p-2}\nabla u$ in $(L^{p'})^N$ since we work in $\mathbb{R}^N$ , but why that implies $-\Delta_p u_n \rightarrow -\Delta_p u$ .

Comment: In your post, you only showed weak convergence of these expressions! If you have $L^{p'}$ convergence then use Hoelder inequality to get the desired convergence.

Comment: @daw hi I know this question is a bit old but I was wondering why does there exist the dominating function g?

Comment: The function $g$ is constructed during the proof that $L^p$-converging sequences have pointwise converging subsequences (or during the proof of completeness of $L^p$).

Comment: Reference: Brezis, Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces, PDEs - Theorem 4.9.